# Promises: combine single resolve methods and Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, promise.all

I have multiple promises fetching different assets. I want to achieve:

1. Executing some code first to handle some of these promises via `then()`.
2. When everything is resolved/fetched, executing some code that launches my app via `Promise.all().then()`.

I need to make sure 1 is excuted before 2. It does seem to work from what I have tested.

```js
// handle promises one by one
promise1.then(results => {});
promise2.then(results => {});

// common process that should come after the above then()s
Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
    .then(results => {});
```

But can I rely on it? Are "*single*" `then()` **always** executed before a `then()` on `Promise.all()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Promise.all is stalled because it waits for all the promises to finish, there is no guarantee that it will resolve after the `.then` call on the promise that resolves last.

Instead you should try creating new promises from the `.then` calls.

```
// handle promises one by one
const promise3 = promise1.then(results => {});
const promise4 = promise2.then(results => {});

// common process that should come after the above then()s
Promise.all([promise3, promise4])
    .then(results => {});
```

This way you can guarantee that the Promise all will resolve after the then calls

Comment: That's the solution I had in mind to overcome this in case my approach wasn't enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can around by using Async/await. With waiting for each promise, you can write code to process data at the end.

Example:

```js
(async () => {
  const responses = [];
  await new Promise((res) => res("promise1")).then((res) => {
    console.log("From promise1 first then");
    responses.push(res);
  });

  // Code at the end to do after all promises
  console.log("Coming from second");
  console.log("Responses:", responses);
})();
```